# Inconsistent results, maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocode

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=rome&sensor=false
OR
---------------------------------------------------------roma-------------

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Vatican%20Museum&sensor=false

If the query is Rome or Roma The result for 
       "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]     is         "long_name" : "Rome",

If the query is "Vatican Museum" The result for 
       "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]     is         "long_name" : "Roma",
and not Rome as it should be.

Is it bug of the service? I try to use language=en but it not helping.

Answer (score 1):

This is complete conjecture so feel free to disregard out of hand, but my best guess is that it has to do with the address that the Maps API has stored. For instance, if you (or I, at least) try searching for the Vatican Museum in [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=vatican%20museum), no result is found and the suggestion points to the Italian version. If you do a similar query for the Colosseum, you can see that your approach of using the `language` parameter does appear to be correct:

**English**

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Colosseum%20rome&sensor=false&language=en

**Italian**

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Colosseum%20rome&sensor=false&language=it

I'll take a look around for some more information corroborating this, but my best guess is that being able to toggle between languages depends on data for that language being available, and in this case only the Italian version is present

Comment: It sound logic for the site name.
The city name have the version in English

Comment: @user1850831 I don't know if it does for that example. It seems like it does for a number of other locations, but that one in particular doesn't seem to have an English translation (see the Google Maps link in the post - the result is in Italian, despite being accessed from an English-based browser).

Comment: The city name should be taken form some DB, the city is exist in english.